# How to create input layer in keras for class label also?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wanted the class label information for my model to build a custom loss function similar to arcface how do i get input values of shape(1) in keras

```
X_input = Input(InputShape)
label = Input(shape=(1,))
#there are some more layers in between 
model = Model(inputs = [X_input,label], outputs = X, name='MNSIT')
newModelArc(InputShape=(108,108,3),number_class=5749)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\FaceRecognition\ClassifyModel.py", line 209, in <module>
    FRmodel = newModelArc(InputShape=(108,108,3),number_class=5749)
  File "D:\FaceRecognition\ClassifyModel.py", line 203, in newModelArc
    model = Model(inputs = [X_input,label], outputs = X, name='MNSIT')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 94, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 241, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1434, in _map_graph_network
    tensor_index=tensor_index)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1421, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1393, in build_map
    node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
[Finished in 6.5s]
```

i get this error

Comment: Labels are not input to the model, they are present only during training, so it makes no sense to do what you are trying to do. What is the problem with just using y_true in your loss?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy in arcface loss you need to input labels along with input data to train,i sorted the issue the issue was not with the input but inside arcface function

Comment: for reference for anyone who read this post the problem was with the output value X, which was none